# Remove 'command not found' error discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

In a discord.py rewrite bot, if someone types the bots prefix and then any text after it, if the text is not found as a command you will get

```
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "sd" is not found
```

Is there anyway to stop the bot from logging this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Write an [`on_command_error`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.on_command_error) error handler that checks if the error is an instance of `CommandNotFound`, and ignores it if it is

```
from discord.ext.commands import CommandNotFound

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, CommandNotFound):
        return
    raise error
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, just change the title and the description inside the "em" part.

```py
@client.event 
async def on_command_error(ctx, error): 
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound): 
        em = discord.Embed(title=f"Error!!!", description=f"Command not found.", color=ctx.author.color) 
        await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, CommandNotFound):
        return
```

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the other answers.