# How to make a display message when argument is incorrect for command discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot and I would like to know how to make an event handler, where when the user invokes a command that doesn't exist, the bot sends a message saying: "That's not a valid command". Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Similar to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52900101/remove-command-not-found-error-discord-py/52900437#52900437), just replace the `return` with an `await ctx.send(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.send("words i guess")
```