# writing a bot for discord in python

Tags: python, discord.py

I've got a working currency system, but we want ways to earn money. So i want to make mini games, so i made a coin flip game but i can't get it to work, it tells me the command is not found when i try it.I also want to make it so the game costs >currency so you *can* win a little bit so basically **betting**

````
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import json
import random
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord import Game
import time
import asyncio
bot = commands.Bot('$')

amounts = {}

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    global amounts
    try:
        with open('amounts.json') as f:
            amounts = json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Could not load amounts.json")
        amounts = {}

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def balance(ctx):
    id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    if id in amounts:
        await ctx.send("You have {} :Ereb: in the bank".format(amounts[id]))
    else:
        await ctx.send("You do not have an account")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def register(ctx):
    id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    if id not in amounts:
        amounts[id] = 100
        await ctx.send("You are now registered")
        _save()
    else:
        await ctx.send("You already have an account")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def transfer(ctx, amount: int, other: discord.Member):
    primary_id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    other_id = str(other.id)
    if primary_id not in amounts:
        await ctx.send("You do not have an account")
    elif other_id not in amounts:
        await ctx.send("The other party does not have an account")
    elif amounts[primary_id] < amount:
        await ctx.send("You cannot afford this transaction")
    else:
        amounts[primary_id] -= amount
        amounts[other_id] += amount
        await ctx.send("Transaction complete")
    _save()

def _save():
    with open('amounts.json', 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(amounts, f)

@bot.command()
async def save():
    _save()

***@bot.command() #problem
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$coinflip'):
        randomlist = ["heads","tails",]
        await client.send_message(message.channel,(random.choice(randomlist)))***

bot.run("token")

    ```
````

Comment: What exception or error are you getting? Where and when does the error occur?

Comment: Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "coinflip" is not found

Comment: Please provide the entire error in the post itself.

Comment: Does this fix your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52900101/remove-command-not-found-error-discord-py

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove 'command not found' error discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52900101/remove-command-not-found-error-discord-py)

Answer (score 0):

You need to decorate your `on_message` callback with `bot.event` instead of `bot.command`.  You also need to add a `bot.process_commands` line so that the other commands are invoked normally.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$coinflip'):
        randomlist = ["heads","tails",]
        await client.send_message(message.channel,(random.choice(randomlist)))
    else:
        await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: I got it to work but it gives out either heads or tails twice.