# Python discord.py display unknown command

Tags: python, discord.py

Im trying to make a log system that logs unknown commands:

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    channel = client.get_channel(test)
    await channel.send(f"**{ctx.author.mention} **SEND COMMAND: ** `{ctx.prefix}{ctx.command.name}` **IN CHANNEL: ** {ctx.channel.mention}!")
```

But sends `None`, any idea?

Comment: *"But sends `None`"* -- because the command is not being executed

Comment: I know, im asking for a fix

Comment: `if isinstance(error, CommandNotFound):` logs the error if the command was not found.

Comment: but can i print it? i tried that before

Comment: check this post,if it helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52900101/remove-command-not-found-error-discord-py

Answer (score 0):

This works well (for my circumstances)

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class NameOfYourBot(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        bot.remove_command('help')
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Logged in as {self.bot.user} ({self.bot.user.id})')


    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        await ctx.send(error)

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("pong")

        
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',description='description', case_insensitive=True)

bot.add_cog(NameOfYourBot(bot))
bot.run('TOKEN')
```

This code is in my setup(login-file for the bot) file and works fine. As output for an undefined command I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdfXG.png)