# catch error if commands.dm_only() returns false

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, discord.py, bots

I want to add a command to my discord bot which is just usable in private chat (DM).

To achieve this I am using [`discord.ext.commands.dm_only`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=dm_only#discord.ext.commands.dm_only). It works as expected but I want to perform a specific event if my `dm_only`-check returns an error, but I don't know how to do this.
Currently the bot just throws an error into my console, but I want to print/send a message to the user (in same public chat) if the chat is public.

Here is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '/')

@commands.command()
@commands.dm_only()
async def command(ctx):
    # do something

client.add_command(command)

client.run(bot_token)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an error handler for that. Either you use the `on_command_error` listener or create a custom error handler.

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
@client.command()
@commands.dm_only()
async def command(ctx):
    await ctx.send("TEST") # Test message

@command.error # Error handler for the "command" command
async def command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.PrivateMessageOnly): # Only usable in DM's
        await ctx.send("You can only use this in DM's!") # Send custom error message
```

Comment: thanks a lot mate, for the rest who runs in similar issues, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52900101/remove-command-not-found-error-discord-py) for `on_command_error` listener